# Can encode/decode a Image Object to keep it in a XML file using Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, serialization, compact-framework

As the title mentioned, I want to encode a Image Obj into some kind of text data (compact framework not support binaryformatter, correct me if I'm wrong). So is there any way to encode a Image Obj into text data and keep it in a XML file for being able to decode from XML file to Image obj later?

UPDATE: Here is what I did following Sam's respose. Thanks Sam!

```
//Write to XML
byte[] Ret;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    myImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    Ret = ms.ToArray();
}
StreamWriter myWrite = new StreamWriter(myPathFile);
myWrite.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(Ret));
myWrite.Flush();
myWrite.Close();
```

Then when I want to decode Image from Base64String to Image:

```
StreamReader StrR = new StreamReader(myPathFile);
BArr = Convert.FromBase64String(StrR.ReadToEnd());
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(BArr,0,BArr.Length))
{
    ms.Write(BArr, 0, BArr.Length);
    listControl1.BGImage = new Bitmap(ms);
}
```

Comment: BTW, your `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: Is using Using block similar to create object then object.Close() or object.Dispose()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically binary data is converted to Base64 when included in XML.  Look at `Convert.ToBase64String`.

Comment: But in compact framework not support binaryformatter. Can you say more details?

Comment: You don't need a binary formatter.  Once you have the image, get the bytes, and pass the byte array to `Convert.ToBase64String`.  If I get a chance I'll update the answer with a sample later.